# Laravel order by relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a query:

```php
 $users =  User::byRole()->inCompany()
        ->with([
            'role'     => function ($q) {
                $q->select('id', 'title')->orderBy('title','DESC');
            },
            'company'  => function ($q) {
                $q->select('id', 'company_name');
            },
            'projects' => function ($q) {
                $q->select('id', 'name');
            },
        ])->select([
            'email',
            'id',
            'company_id',
        ])->paginate();
```

The issue is that it wont order by the role title.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: `->select([
            'email',
            'id',
            'company_id',
        ])->orderBy('title','DESC')->paginate();`

Comment: @tech2017 that wont work because i wont to order by the relationships field.

Comment: You need to use a join clause when ordering by related fields.

Comment: What is the relation between user and role? hasMany?

Comment: Why don't you just write in plain sql instead of that semi crap code?

Comment: @ChiragPatel yes its hasmany

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modified `withCount()`:

```php
$users =  User::byRole()->inCompany()
    ->with([
        'role'     => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'title');
        },
        'company'  => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'company_name');
        },
        'projects' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'name');
        },
    ])->select([
        'email',
        'id',
        'company_id',
    ])->withCount(['role as title' => function ($q) {
        $q->select('title');
    })->orderBy('title', 'DESC')
    ->paginate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You also use `join` like this,

```
->join('roles','roles.id','user.role_id')
...
...
->orderBy('roles.title', 'DESC')
```

I hope this will help you